# Is it possible to have an =if equation involving text and math?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2013

This is what I'm shooting for:

=IF(LEFT(Q3,2)="By","see authorizing lab"&"-"&SUM(Q3-L3))

I'm trying to say IF Q3 says "By" the return "see authorizing lab" if not then subtract L3 from Q3 (both cells are dates) and return how many days have past.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like cell `Q3` is of the format `By [date]`. Excel sees this as a text value, not a date value. Thus, you can not do something like `Q3-L3`. I'm guessing that's where the confusion comes in. You have a few option to resolve the issue depending on how your data is setup. Before we get into those, let's clean up your formula. I *think* you want to *either* show the text "See authorizing lab" *or* show how many days until it's expected to be ready. If that is the case, the formula should be

```
=IF(LEFT(Q3,2)="By", "See authorizing lab", Q3-L3)
```

Now, for the `Q3-L3` part, we need to extract a date value from a text value. There's a function for that. Since we want to skip the first 3 characters (`By`), we'll also use the `MID` function.

```
DATEVALUE(MID(Q3,4,LEN(Q3)))
```

That will extract all the text starting with the fourth character and try to convert it to a date value. Plugging that into the rest of the formula gives us:

```
=IF(LEFT(Q3,2)="By", "See authorizing lab", DATEVALUE(MID(Q3,4,LEN(Q3)))-L3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly do this, there is no reason that you can't have text and math in the same `IF` function.

Your example doesn't follow the format of an `IF` function, which is:

```
=IF(logical_test, value_if_true, value_if_false)
```

That is, you need to separate each part by a comma. So your code should read:

```
=IF(LEFT(Q3,2)="By", "see authorizing lab", Q3-L3)
```

(Also, there is no need to use the `SUM` function unless you are trying to add a range of numbers.)

Comment: You missed a subtle point Engineer Toast noticed.  If Q3 starts with "By", then the date it contains is part of a text string and needs to be extracted and converted to a date before you can do the Q3-L3 subtraction.